# Reading the virtual function table (vtable) pointer?

Tags: c++, memory

Is there a well-defined way of accessing the vtable of a class? When debugging in visual studio I can expand 'this' like: this->_ptr->__vfptr. But this path does not seem to be available from code.

I need this for a unit test of a custom heap implementation (embedded environment).

**Background**

We had a bug where an object being allocated on our custom heap (which isn't anything more than an array of a certain size) was working as expected until we wanted to add an object having a virtual function (it took quite some time before we realized that this addition was the cause of the problem). The mistake that we did was to assign an object to memory where no object had been initialized prior to assignment. We did not pay much attention when writing that code and as it worked with everything else and was tested, we considered it working. Here's some sample code:

```
int array_ptr[sizeof(SomeObject)];
*((SomeObject*) array_ptr) = SomeObject(); // Does only partially initialize the object!
```

Once we realized this line was the issue, it also became clear why that was the case.

Comment: Not a standard or portable way, at least. Its existence is an implementation detail, and its contents or layout implementation-defined. What are your unit tests going to _do_ with the address of a vtable anyway?

Comment: @Useless Too bad if that's the case. I need to verify that the vtable has a valid address. But I can do it in the unspecific way too, i.e. try to call a virtual function and get an "unknown exception". I was just hoping I could generate a nice "vtable not properly copied" fail message.

Comment: @LukasKalinski: "I need to verify that the vtable has a valid address." Great! That means you are writing unit tests for the compiler?

Comment: @Klaus No, that means that we're testing that objects created on our custom heap are properly initialized. We just had a bug that was extremely hard to track down due to objects not being properly initialized when having virtual functions.

Comment: Does your custom heap have a debug mode where it fills uninitialized memory with a sentry bit-pattern? If you see a pointer value of `0xdeadbeef`, that's a pretty strong hint it's uninitialized.

Comment: @LukasKalinski: Vtable-Init is compiler generated code. If *you* write a bug which is able to break that behavior, I believe you are doing very strange things...

Comment: "vtable not properly copied". Am I the only one who thinks this points at a mistaken assumption? Objects are copied, but objects usually do not contain vtables. They contain vtable _pointers_. That's why Visual Studio shows `__vfptr`. And I suspect the "extremely hard to track down bug" was due to the assumption that you can `memcpy` objects. that is true *only* for objects that do not contain virtual functions. This restriction is exactly due to vtables, pointers to vtables, or yet other mechanisms. The Standard does not assume those can be copied.

Comment: @MSalters That was just a typo, of course I meant vtable pointer. It is funny that you mention memcpy as a problem, because memcpy actually solved the issue for us (i.e. it copies the vtable pointer). However, we will be using placement new to solve this. But before solving this, it would be nice to have a test catching the problem.

Comment: @Klaus If you're here only to make ironic comments without taking the time to understand what the problem is, maybe you should spend your time doing something else?

Comment: @LukasKalinski: Sorry if it sounds ironic. But my experience is, that writing own heap environment could not end in corrupted vtable pointers. Pointing the libstdc++ components to own memory handlers will not effect vtable pointer generation, only the address management under them. So if you see *only* corrupted vtables, you  have a different problem.

Comment: @Klaus It's OK. Please, see my updated question to get some insight into how the problem arised.

Comment: @LukasKalinski: ?? "uninitialized memory." Means initialized pointer  or means not initialized memory hardware, like unset memory controller issues? In both cases, the vtable pointer is not the problem! Memory Controller -> Check standard patterns for mem check, unitialized pointer -> use cross compile and valgrind to get this problems quite easy.

Comment: @Klaus Sorry about wrong terminology, I meant memory where no object had been initialized prior to assignment (I have corrected my question). Thanks for your tips, I will keep them in mind for the future. In this case, however, the vtable pointer was the problem, as it was set to 0x0 for the object on the custom heap. Only removing the virtual function or using memcpy solved the issue.

Comment: If I understand your code and background correctly, the problem is that you're using an assignment operator to initialize an object (`*array_ptr`). If so, this is a plain C++ bug, which is unrelated to your custom allocator. The vptr is uninitialized because it is normally set by the (compiler generated) part of the constructor, but you never properly construct the object on the left side of the assignment.

Comment: @eran Yes, that's exactly what we learned, the hard way... Now I wanted to catch that in a test case, but it seems I'll have to give up that idea.

Comment: If you really want to test this, you can create an object of the same type in a way you know will work for sure (basically just `new SomeObject`), get the vptr using a cast and compare to the suspected object you're testing. But given there's so many ways to invoke UB in C++, I'm not sure testing this particular case is valuable.

Comment: @eran: The compiler would be entirely justified in optimizing out that code. "Left side is the vptr of a `CFoo` object, right side is the vptr of a `CFoo` object, of course they are equal". That's the chief problem with UB, it especially breaks optimizers.

Answer (score 3):

Aha, I get it now, with the clarification from the comments.

You're calling `CFoo::operator=` on raw memory that only has the *size* of a `CFoo`. That's indeed not going to set a vtable, on common implementations. This is specific to how assignment in C++ works. Object assignment in C++ is defined to be *slicing*. If you assign a `Derived` object to a `Base` class, you're calling `Base::operator=(Base const& src)`. This only copies the Base sub-object of the `Derived` object.

The reason why C++ chose this model is because that means the `Base` object doesn't change size when you assign a `Derived` value to it, at the obvious price of losing the extra information.

The net effect is that C++ objects do not change type after construction. Practically, that means the type, **and the vtable** can be fixed by the constructor. The assignment operator won't touch it.

So, by calling the assignment operator on raw memory, you get Undefined Behavior, in particular an uninitialized (garbage) vtable. You can't count on it being all zeroes. Also, in more complicated cases with multiple and virtual inheritance, there are additional data fields to find the various sub-objects. Those would be uninitialized as well. Note that these additional data fields may contain absolute pointers. `memcpy` such an object, and you'd point back to subobjects of the original.

Can you detect this? No. All your attempts to access the memory are Undefined Behavior, by virtue of there not being a `CFoo` object in the raw memory.

The solution is placement `new`. This is the magical incantation that turns raw memory into an object. It can use any constructor, including move constructors and copy constructors, but (barring exceptions) will leave you with a valid object, with proper polymorphic behavior.

Comment: In short: **assignment** copies an object onto an **existing** object. A **constructor** copies an object into raw memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so learning from MSalters and other commenters above I understand there is no straight forward way of reading the vtable pointer. However, I came up with a solution that was enough for my needs (i.e. to test that the vtable pointer is properly initialized). So here's the code (note that I *assume* that what I get is the vtable pointer as sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(EmptyClassWithOneVirtualFunction)):

```
class EmptyClassWithOneVirtualFunction
{
    virtual void testFunction() {}
};

void test_staticNew_object_vtable()
{
    EmptyClassWithOneVirtualFunction correctObject;

    EmptyClassWithOneVirtualFunction* object = mem::static_new<EmptyClassWithOneVirtualFunction>();

    size_t* correctObjectVtablePtr  = ( (size_t*) &correctObject );
    size_t* objectVtablePtr         = ( (size_t*) object );
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS( *objectVtablePtr, *correctObjectVtablePtr );
}
```

It should be pointed out that this is test code that is built in debug mode without optimization. To be able to catch this error even in this not entirely "safe" way is more valuable to me than to skip doing it just because there is no right way to do it.

Comment: Which reminds me, "**the** vtable pointer" is already a broken assumption. Most implementations are known to sometimes use multiple.

Comment: @MSalters You're probably right, but it doesn't matter in this particular case. I'm not using the vtable to anything else than to verify that it's intact (i.e. != 0). And even if there are more vtable pointers, checking that one of them is intact should be enough to make sure the bug is not reintroduced in the future.